# document.querySelectorAll() only gets last <li> item

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, jquery-selectors

I want to store the original texts of all items with the .glitch class. Therefore, I used `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all of them, but only the last <li> item gets stored.

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li id="1" class="focusable glitch">Home</li>
            <li id="2" class="focusable glitch">Projects</li>
            <li id="3" class="focusable glitch">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.glitch').forEach(item => {
    originalTexts[item] = item.innerHTML;
});
```

The dicionary I save the texts in (I added two more items to see if it gets them):

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement]: " Example Header"
[object HTMLLIElement]: "Contact"
[object HTMLParagraphElement]: "Example Paragraph"
```

As you can see it only stores one HTMLLIElement. How can I store all of them?

Comment: Well the key (property) is a string so you would need something else to map it by.

Comment: What is `originalTexts`? How/where is it declared? How/when is the code you posted invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
originalTexts[item] = item.innerHTML;
```

implicitly converts `item` to string, then assigns a value to the resulting property. The string will be the same for all the `li` items: `"[object HTMLLIElement]"`. So the second loop iteration onward **write over** the previous loop iteration's value.

You'll need to use unique identifiers. One way to do that is to use the index that your callback receives as a second argument in combination with the string (or if the `li`s all have IDs, as yours do, that would work), but I think I'd pick some other string as the basis for the name.

Example (but again, I'd pick some other string, rather than implicitly converting `item` to string):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.glitch').forEach((item, index) => {
    originalTexts[`${item}_${index}`] = item.innerHTML;
});
```

Live Copy:

```js
const originalTexts = {};
document.querySelectorAll('.glitch').forEach((item, index) => {
    originalTexts[`${item}_${index}`] = item.innerHTML;
});
console.log(originalTexts);
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
        <li id="1" class="focusable glitch">Home</li>
        <li id="2" class="focusable glitch">Projects</li>
        <li id="3" class="focusable glitch">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: How do I access a specific item afterwards. Is it possible to identify the index only if I have got the item?

Comment: @Lucadmin If you needed to get a specific element, it is much easier to use the `id` (which is unique).

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to get around the work to give every object an id, but solved it with ids now

Answer (score 3):

You should use the item's id as the key instead of the item itself, as it will be converted to a string and all `<li>` elements will be converted to `"[object HTMLLIElement]"`. As you are always assigning a value to the same property of the object, its value ends up as the `innerHTML` of the last `<li>` element.

```js
const originalTexts = {};
document.querySelectorAll('.glitch').forEach(item => {
  originalTexts[item.id] = item.innerHTML;
});
console.log(originalTexts);
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li id="1" class="focusable glitch">Home</li>
    <li id="2" class="focusable glitch">Projects</li>
    <li id="3" class="focusable glitch">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is a string so it is performing item.toString() when it is making the property. Hence why they keep overwriting each other.

You either need to use an array or use something that is unique for the property.

```js
// Array
const originalTexts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.glitch')).map(item => item.innerHTML);

console.log(originalTexts)

// Using id
const originalTexts2 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.glitch')).reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item.id] = item.innerHTML) && obj, {});

console.log(originalTexts2)
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li id="1" class="focusable glitch">Home</li>
    <li id="2" class="focusable glitch">Projects</li>
    <li id="3" class="focusable glitch">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```